# Is there a way to generate random points with a given line of best fit However with one of those points already specified

Tags: line, linear-regression, linear-algebra

It is possible to generate random points from a given line of best fit. refrenced in this stackoverflow [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152028/i-have-a-line-of-best-fit-i-need-data-points-that-will-not-change-my-line-of-be) as well as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139928/simulating-data-with-a-lot-of-predefined-constraints-in-r/139937#139937) I also found proof of this methodology [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Eaditya/resources/LectureSIX.pdf). It essentially involves regressing random y values against your x values to find an orthogonal vector of residuals. What im wondering is if this or a similar technique could be used to still find an appropriate scatter plot with the given R^2 and LOBF. But with one of those points fixed to an exact value. And how would someone calculate the range that value could fall in?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only a line that is expected to be fit to a specific equation you can simply generate random points, on the line and add to them a random value.

A few ideas (as open as your question).

You generate random `x[i]` and then random `y[i] = m * x[i] + b + dy[i]` where `dy[i]` and ``x[i] * dy[i]` have zero mean.

Other approach is to (1) generate random points, (1)find the best fit, (3) find the transformation (rotation and translation if 2D) that takes the fitted line to the expected line, (4) apply the same transformation found in step 3 to the poitns generates in step 1.